# Authenticating via Keycloak in an iframe

Tags: javascript, authentication, iframe, keycloak

I am trying to include authentication via keycloak in an existing software that is extendable via custom javascript. Other solutions like the Google AAI work just fine, but I am having issues with keycloak. Problem is that the extendable authentication widget is displayed in an iframe, thus the standard `keycloak.login()` method does not work because displaying of keycloak in an iframe is disabled, which as I understand is also the correct behaviour.

Trying to work around that I used the `keycloak.createLoginUrl()` to open the authentication in a new window, which also works and lets me successfully authenticate via my third party. But now I need to access the token that is returned upon successful login via keycloak to start an authenticated session in my software, which is the point I am struggling with right now, because the keycloak object is still considered as unauthenticated and no message event is triggered I believe I am missing something obvious in the workings of keycloak, maybe somebody sees the error in my ways. The following code is the entire login procedure, where `window.parent.postMessage(message, "*");` passes the token back to the software.

```
window.onload =  function () {
        keycloak = new Keycloak({...
        });

        keycloak.onTokenExpired = function () {
          keycloak
            .updateToken(30)
            .success(() => {
              console.log("Successfully got a new token", keycloak.token);
              let message = {
                type: "customAuthentication",
                token: keycloak.token,
              };
              window.parent.postMessage(message, "*");
            })
            .error(() => {
              console.log("Error upon refreshing the keycloak token");
            });
        };

       keycloak
          .init({
            checkLoginIframe: false,
          })
          .then(function (authenticated) {
            if (authenticated) {
              console.log(keycloak);
              let message = {
                token: keycloak.token,
              };

              if (window.opener) {
                message.type = "keycloakAuthSuccess";
                window.opener.postMessage(message, "*");
                window.close();
              } else {
                message.type = "customAuthentication";
                window.parent.postMessage(message, "*");
              }
            } else {
              const button = document.getElementById(
                "button-custom-keycloak-login"
              );
              button.onclick = function () {
                window.open(keycloak.createLoginUrl({
                    redirectUri : "..."
                }), "Keycloak login popup");
              };
            }
          });

        window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
          let message = event.data;
          if (message && message.type === "signOut") {
            keycloak.logout();
          } else if (message && message.type === "keycloakAuthSuccess") {
            keycloak.login();
          }
        });
      };
```